# sounds problem with ubuntu: port changing by itself

Tags: sound

I have a computer with Ubuntu 20.04 and with Linux Mint. I have same problem with both system. Sometime, sounds switch off. Then come back. then scitch off ...

I can see in pavucontrol the port is "switching":

[image]

Switching from "Sortie ligne" to "Casque audio".

What can i do to investigate ?
thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think [this thread](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=242742) from Linux Mint forum may help.